# Why was my flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

I am aware what does disputed flag mean. I have flagged an answer as **not an answer**, because in my opinion, it does not answer the question, at least not in a way that it would help the OP and I think that the answer should be a comment.

Am I wrong?

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785080/how-can-i-get-fragment-by-tag/27785784#27785784).

**Edit:**

The answer was deleted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If an answer is wrong - downvote it.

If an answer isn't trying to answer the question at all - only then flag as *not an answer*.

This could be the case for answers like

- Me too
- Anyone found the answer yet?
- Responses to real answers
- Could you clarify your question?
- ....

Comment: So you would say, this is an legit answer to the question?

Comment: Sure. Even the OP thanked the answerer for the answer. And if it would be a bad answer - no need for a moderator  to step in. Let the community familiar with the topic handle it. A moderator should not have to make a judgement how good the answer is

Comment: I agree, it does answer the question in a way, but does not really help the OP, or provide with an alternative. I  thought it should be a comment. Thanks for your clarification!